# Show two integrals are equal

Tags: integration

Consider an identity (equation) in variables $P$ and $Q$. $P(Q)$ denotes the identity when $P$ is written in terms of $Q$ and $Q(P)$ denotes the identity when $Q$ is written in terms of $P$.

For example, if $Q + bP - a = 0$ is the identity, then $Q(P) = a - bP$ and $P(Q) = (1/b)(a - Q)$.

Can we show that $$\int_{P_0}^{P_\max} Q(P) dP = \int_{0}^{Q_0} [P(Q) - P_0] dQ$$

given $(Q_0, P_0)$ solves the identity and $Q(P_\max) = 0$?

**My attempt:**

$$\int_{0}^{Q_0} [P(Q) - P_0] dQ = \left(\int_{0}^{Q_0} P(Q)dQ\right) - P_0Q_0 = \int_{P_{\max}}^{P_0} P(Q) Q'(P) dP = ?$$

Comment: there is no such thing as variables in mathematics, maybe in logic or physics but not in mathematics. Can you be more precise about what you try to mean when you say that $P$ and $Q$ are equal as variables?

Comment: @Masacroso Let's say $P = 5 - 2Q$. Then for any given $P = \bar{P}$, $Q(\bar{P}) = (5-\bar{P})/2$ and similarly we can say for $Q = \bar{Q}$. I just wanted to explain what $P(Q)$ and $Q(P)$ mean. Also, $P$ and $Q$ are not equal: they just follow an identity equation (like $P - 5 + 2Q = 0$ in this example).